# Read authentication protected csv in PHP

Tags: php, csv

I'm trying to fetch a data from csv file from a server that requires authentication.

I have the following PHP code:

```
$username = 'test';
$password = 'test1234';

$context = stream_context_create(array('http' => array('header'  => "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode("$username:$password"))));

$url = "http://www.example.com/userinfo.csv";
$user_info = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

var_dump($user_info);
return;
```

I tried with cURL as well with the following code:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_DIGEST);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);

var_dump($output);
return;
```

**When i  run csv URL in browser & pass authentication details, csv file directly gets download.**

The cURL returns a  `[http_code] => 200` in the `$info` and the `$output` is empty.

I'm a PHP/server newbie, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think you might have to tell libcurl to support cookies. See `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR`. Your browser does support cookies.

Comment: Tip: Switch cookies off in your browser to test if that's the problem.